# Помогите со знаками, пожалуйста!

Tags: пунктуация

*Правда это красиво?*
Нужны ли здесь вообще какие-то знаки препинания, и, если нужны, то какие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Правда, это красиво?**

Из словаря:

**ПРАВДА, в зн. частицы.**  Употр. **в вопросе, требующем подтверждения.**
Хорошо, что ты пришёл. - Правда?
Если нельзя, но хочется, то можно, **правда**?

[правда | gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0&all=x)

Хотя слово находится в препозиции, но по значению это именно вопрос, требующий подтверждения.